# Searching words based on user input in js

Tags: javascript

So I have the below setup where a user inputs text and I want to see if any of the inputted characters match the words. It all works great when I input say.

```
const input = 'memb';
```

but if do something like this.

```
 const input = 'member has';
```

Then it returns false. It should stay true if it finds a match of characters which it does, member is a match. Member has is also a match as the characters m, e, m, b, e, r is still a match event though h, a, s doesn't match any the other words.

Anyone know how I can get it to keep returning true if the characters match ?

```js
const input = 'member has';
const inputLower = input.toLowerCase();
const words = ['member', 'support', 'life'];
const result = words.some(word => {
  const words = word.split(',');
  return words.some(r => r.toLowerCase().includes(inputLower));
});

console.log('result = ', result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the reverse logic, where you also check whether `inputLower` includes `r`:

```js
const input = 'memb has';
let inputLower = input.toLowerCase();
const words = ['member', 'support', 'life'];
const result = words.some(word => {
  const words = word.split(',');
  return words.some(r => {
    if (~inputLower.indexOf( " " )) {
    // only check the first word if there are multiple
      inputLower = inputLower.substring( 0, inputLower.indexOf( " " ) );
    }
    return r.toLowerCase().includes(inputLower) || inputLower.includes(r.toLowerCase());
  });
});

console.log('result = ', result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but this only works if you have all the word in there not just some characters. Test it using const input = 'memb'; and it returns false. there is m, e, m, b in the words so it should return true.

Comment: Ah I never thought of that. Works great thank you for the help.

Comment: Hi, I edited the code to accommodate that behaviour if that's what you want to happen. It simply only checks the first word (see: `indexOf`), you'll have to change it yourself depending on what circumstances you want it to work.

Comment: Ah but I want it to check all words and check them by each character inputted. If you see my comment and my fiddle you can see what I'm trying to do. Thanks again for the help

Comment: You'll need to set specific groundrules, if you're checking every character for every word, you're going to run into a lot of trouble, such as  words having the same starting letters, but ending differently. Just split the string then by spaces, and loop over every character of every word and put some conditionals in for whatever rules you want.